# Установка многофайлового .apk на смартфон Meizu

Tags: android, установка, apk

Есть проблема (конкретно с MyVodafone) с моим Meizu - через GooglePlay ставит только древнюю версию 1.0.0 (не работает Meizu с Google play), а в поддержке водафона шлют чуть ли не матом - что нужно **только** через Google и что сам .apk-файл они не дадут - типа, его и нет. Хотя когда-то давали... Из файла-то ставилось нормально.

Нашел программку raccoon, скачал с GooglePlay - а там челй набор файлов:

```
20 839 842 config.armeabi_v7a-101193672.apk
    23 451 config.ru-101193672.apk
   418 115 config.xhdpi-101193672.apk
32 942 185 ua.vodafone.myvodafone-101193672.apk
```

Я нахально попробовал поставить последний - но он после установки заявил о несоответствии процессора. Как я понимаю, остальные файлы именно для этого и нужны... Но нак правильно установить такой пакет - не знаю. Найти в Интернете не могу.

Расскажите пожалуйста, что делать, как это правильно установить.

И заодно - как скачивать с GooglePlay так, чтоб никакую гадость не закачать.

Comment: Попробуй по очереди все установить. Наверное, MyVodafone загружено на маркет не как апк, а как bundle и для скачки выдаются только те модули, которые нужны именно для конкретного устройства, а не все приложение целиком.

Comment: @Эникейщик А в каком порядке устанавливаьть?... Попробовал было - нет, "Ошибка разбора пакета"...